# reflections.getTypesAnnotatedWith(...) finds class, but getAnnotations().length is 0

Tags: java, reflection, reflections

When using the Java [reflections library](http://code.google.com/p/reflections/) I can correctly find classes decorated with an annotation:

```
Set<Class<?>> annotated = reflections.getTypesAnnotatedWith(CommandName.class);
```

but when I try to see how many annotations are on each class I always see zero:

```
for(Class c : annotated)
{
     int numAnnotations = c.getAnnotations().length;
}
```

Why does `c.getAnnotations()` return an array of length 0? In fact, in the debugger, all the fields (except `name`) of `c` are `null`.

Comment: Regarding your final sentence, I think much of the metadata within `Class` instances is lazily loaded.

Comment: Under this assumption should not calling getAnnotations() for the first time force at least the annotations array to populate?

Comment: Yeah, that should definitely happen. I just meant that the debugger was probably misleading. +1 to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ack, turns out annotations aren't preserved to runtime unless you mark them with @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME).  This fixed it.  Strange that the class was included in the set though.  I would think it would be all or nothing.